# css help. I'm trying to keep all the eye pieces relative to each other as the screen expands and shrinks

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a CSS art eye where all the parts of the eye stay together when the screen shrinks or expands. Currently the pupil moves all over the place. Any thoughts?

It's not letting me submit as the code/comment ratio is not below the threshold. hopefully now.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

p {
  top: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.eye-outline {
  width: 600px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.eye-white {
  width: 580px;
  height: 330px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 3%;
  left: 1.8%;
}

.iris-outline {
  width: 325px;
  height: 325px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  left: 23%;
  bottom: 97%;
}

.iris {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  bottom: 186.5%;
  left: 25%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.pupil {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  left: 20%;
  top: -20%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<a href="index.html">back</a>
<main>
  <h1>eye</h1>
</main>

<div class="eye-outline">
  <div class="eye-white"></div>
  <div class="iris-outline"></div>
  <div class="iris"></div>
</div>
<div class="pupil"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> refactored your code, now it won't have repeated code, and not hard-coded left, top. (everything is centered automatically)

[image]

> for responsive example, see next snippet (not this below)

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.eye-outline,
.eye-white,
.iris,
.pupil,
.iris-outline {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.eye-outline {
  position: relative;
}


/* the most important part, centering correctly */

.eye-white,
.iris,
.pupil,
.iris-outline {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.eye-outline,
.iris-outline,
.pupil {
  background-color: black;
}

.eye-outline {
  width: 600px;
  height: 350px;
}

.eye-white {
  width: 580px;
  height: 330px;
  background-color: white;
}

.iris-outline {
  width: 325px;
  height: 325px;
}

.iris {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.pupil {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}


/* not important, only debugging purposes */

body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="eye-outline">
  <div class="eye-white"></div>
  <div class="iris-outline"></div>
  <div class="iris"></div>
  <div class="pupil"></div>
</div>
```

---

### responsive example

here I changed the `px` to `vmin` making the project 100% responsive!

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.eye-outline,
.eye-white,
.iris,
.pupil,
.iris-outline {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.eye-outline {
  position: relative;
}


/* the most important part, centering correctly */

.eye-white,
.iris,
.pupil,
.iris-outline {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.eye-outline,
.iris-outline,
.pupil {
  background-color: black;
}

/* for finding this vmin values
1. get your px values
2. divide px value by 100 (px/100)
3. add 20 to the vmin value 

> so the max width is 80vmin and all other are smaller (I suggest maximum 95vmin, if you want to add 30)
*/
.eye-outline {
  width: 80vmin;
  height: 55vmin;
}

.eye-white {
  width: 78vmin;
  height: 53vmin;
  background-color: white;
}

.iris-outline {
  width: 52.5vmin;
  height: 52.5vmin;
}

.iris {
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
  background-color: blue;
}

.pupil {
  width: 35vmin;
  height: 35vmin;
}


/* not important, only debugging purposes */

body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="eye-outline">
  <div class="eye-white"></div>
  <div class="iris-outline"></div>
  <div class="iris"></div>
  <div class="pupil"></div>
</div>
```

mobile:

[image]

small height device:
[image]

desktop:

[image]